# Facebook API Page Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our web development firm is requesting a page access token. Currently, the only page access token we can generate provides full admin access and we do not want to share any advertising spend, post insights or analytics information with the web development firm. **The objective of the API key / page access token is to pull content from our Facebook business page and display it on our new site, only.**

Is it possible to create a page access token / API key with limited permissions? and what are the steps required? I was unable to find any specific documentation on the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each Token can include different permissions. The most basic Page Token only includes the `manage_pages` permission, in addition you can add `publish_pages` which allows to post to a Page with the Token, or `read_insights` to get access to Page insights. A list of possible permissions can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

In your case, a Page Token with only the `manage_pages` permission will be good enough.